# AnkhSVN Glyphs on folders

Tags: visual-studio-2008, ankhsvn

I have recently switched to the latest version of AnkhSVN for VS2008. Everything is working fine except I couldn't work out how to make glyphs appear on folders. Files indicate their status just fine but folders do not indicate whether their content has changed or not.
I found this FAQ entry explaining that glyphs do not work on normal project types:  http://ankhsvn.open.collab.net/wiki/Faq#head-88630ae09ebe716a8edd451fe675bf560b14a118

Is there any workaround to get the glyphs to show up? The pending changes window is ok but I would prefer to have some sort of indication on the actual folder in the solution explorer.

Thanks,
b3n

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Visual Studio isn't querying (pulling) SCC providers for folder glyphs, the only way to get them there is by using a hack to set the glyph on the folder manually (pushing). The AnkhSVN project decided to not use this hack, and rely on the support API provided by the Visual Studio SDK.

The pulling API is also a lot more efficient because VS will only pull the glyph when it's visible. When pushing the visibility can't be determined, so the glyph always has to be pushed.

Comment: Do you know if there is a workaround/addon to show glyphs on the folders?

Answer (score -1):

Check out [VisualSVN for Visual Studio](http://www.visualsvn.com/visualsvn/): It properly integrates to Visual Studio and displays status icons for all items in Solution Explorer including folders.